# move document to another site collection workflow

Tags: 2010, archive

I wrote a simple program which moves me items from one Document Library to another Document Library (another site collection).

The program create a new file in the second Document Library with all metadatas.

I would like to ask if is possible to transfer information about workflow to the second Document Library?

I choosed this way becouse my Database is too big and I need to archive some items to reduce the main database. How about workflows?

I'm using SharePoint 2010.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, this is technically not possible! The SharePoint API does not provide any means of programmatically creating a workflow history without actually running the workflows. You could of course copy the task items in the workflow history list - but the workflow instance ids will be broken.